# Django - Optional recursive relationship

Tags: database, django, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to use Django to create a recursive relationship, which gives users a folder-like hierarchical structure in which to place resources.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I know I could use treebeard or mptt to create a nested set but I have read that making changes to the tree structure (something that would be happening a lot in this case) can be quite an intensive operation as a lot of fields have to be updated.

On the other hand, I could folder model with a ForeignKey to self but how do I manage the top level folders with no foreign key value?  Will Django complain if I just set this value to be NULL?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A foreign key can be be defined as `fk = models.ForeignKey('MyModel', null=True, blank=True)` so that it can be left null in the DB. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if this would cause a problem with Django or not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treebeard actually supports three different tree implementations, just choose the one that will suite your needs.

- Adjacency List (fast writes at the cost of slow reads)
- Materialized Path (probably the fastest way of working with trees in SQL)
- Nested Sets (very efficient reads at the cost of high maintenance on write/delete operations)

Docs are here: https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/tip/